# label on top of image in python

Tags: python, image, tkinter, label

I am trying to display text on top of an image. Right now the text is below the image or if I put a row=0 in the grid disappears. I am assuming it is behind the image. I can't seem to get it to work. My code is:

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk
import csv
import time

root = Tk()

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='C:\Users\Shawn\PycharmProjects\Test\Background.gif')

var0 = StringVar()
var1 = StringVar()
var2 = StringVar()
var3 = StringVar()

label0 = Label(root, fg="white", textvariable=var0)
label1 = Label(root, fg="white", textvariable=var1)
label2 = Label(root, fg="white", textvariable=var2)
label3 = Label(root, fg="white", textvariable=var3)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
def csv_dict_reader(file_obj):
    reader = csv.DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=',')
    for column in reader:
        if (column["Week"]) == (time.strftime("%U")):
            var0.set(column["Parashat"])
            var1.set(column["Torah"])
            var2.set(column["Haftarah"])
            var3.set(column["Gospel"])

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("Torah.csv") as f_obj:
        csv_dict_reader(f_obj)

Label(root, image=image).grid(row=0, column=0)
label0.grid()
label1.grid()
label2.grid()
label3.grid()
mainloop()
```

I have tried putting the row and column in the label0.grid(row=1, column=1), along with all labels and all row and column numbers.

The outcome I want is label0 - label3 to be centered on top of the image. The image is black and dark blue so the white text will show well. Thank you.

Shawn

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding the text option to the label with your photo in. Then look at the [compound](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm) feature to format it. It would look like this:

```
label=Label(image=image, text="Text", compound="center")
```

Comment: I have tried that, but since I am labeling using an if statement all i get is numbers and not the data I am looking for. Its not static text that I am using, but data called from a .csv file that depends on the week what data is shown. I tried:

Comment: I have tried that, but since I am labeling using an if statement all i get is numbers and not the data I am looking for. Its not static text that I am using, but data called from a .csv file that depends on the week what data is shown. I tried:    label=Label(image=image, text=text0, compound="center")  and my result is:  the picture with .52036512 on it when it is supposed to be the picture with Chayei Sarah. Just not sure what I am doing  wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In the below code the orgin postion is set to (0,0) it belong to the top left corner

```
import cv2
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
orgin = (0, 0) 
fontScale = 1
color = (255, 0, 0) 
thickness = 2
image = cv2.putText(image, 'OpenCV', orgin, font,  
               fontScale, color, thickness, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

Comment: Sure  here after i will give a explanation.Thank you